# parse a function with pyparsing

Tags: python, function, parsing, lua, pyparsing

I am trying to parse some LUA functions with pyparsing. It also works for almost everything I need except one case where the last parameter is just a word.

So this is my code. This is my first parser using pyparsing but I did my best to structure it logically:

To explain my comments within the code:

`trigger_async(<object>, <name>, <param>)`

`trigger_async(<parameters>)`

`<param> = <name> = <type>`

```
def parse_events_from_text(text):
    variable = Word(alphanums + "-_.:()")

    # Entity on which the event will be triggered
    obj = variable.setResultsName("object")

    # Name of the event
    name = (quotedString + Optional(Suppress("..") + variable)).setResultsName("name")

    # Parameter List of the event
    paramName = variable.setResultsName("name")
    paramType = variable.setResultsName("type")
    param = Group(paramName + Suppress("=") + paramType).setResultsName("parameter")
    paramList = Group(Optional(Suppress("{") + ZeroOrMore(delimitedList(param)) + Suppress("}"))).setResultsName("parameters")

    function_parameter = obj | name | paramList

    # Function Start
    trigger = "trigger"
    async = Optional("_async")

    # Function Call
    functionOpening = Combine(trigger + async + "(").setResultsName("functionOpening")
    functionCall = ZeroOrMore(Group(functionOpening + delimitedList(function_parameter) + Suppress(")")))

    resultsList = functionCall.searchString(text)

    results = []

    for resultsL in resultsList:
        if len(resultsL) != 0:
            if resultsL not in results:
                results.append(resultsL)

    return results
```

So the parser was written for those kinds of events:

```
trigger(self._entity, 'game:construction:changed', { entity = target })`
trigger_async(entity, 'game:heal:healer_damaged', { healer = entity })`
trigger_async(entity, 'game:heal:healer_damaged', { healer = entity, entity = target, test = party})`
trigger_async(entity, 'game:heal:healer')`
trigger(entity.function(), 'game:heal:healer', {})`
```

**But the problem** is if there aren't any curly braces:

```
trigger(entity, 'game:heal:healer', entity.test)
```

it won't work because of my declared variable

```
variable = Word(alphanums + "-_.:()")
```

where braces are allowed so the parser is confused with the last one which is "missing" for the function end. If I would write

```
trigger(entity,'game:heal:healer',entity.test))
```

it would work.

I sat down and wanted to rewrite the parser but I dont know how? Somehow I must tell that it is only valid if the `variable` has 1 open bracket and 1 closing bracket like so:

```
trigger(entity,'game:heal:healer',entity.test(input))
```

else don't eat up that closing brace.

```
trigger(entity,'game:heal:healer',entity.test) <-- Variable, don't eat it!
```

Comment: Why are the parentheses part of `variable`?

Comment: because within the object or within a single param there could be a function call like `trigger(ecs.get_entity(), 'game:heal:healer', ecs.get_healed_person())`

Comment: That's still not a variable. You need to actually parse the real, recursive structure of Lua expressions. Faking it by folding `-_.:()` into your definition of a variable won't cut it.

Comment: So do you mean I need to think about the reversed way? I started with the outer function call and went inside. Do you mean I need to firstly search for the inner structure and at the end check if it's surrounded by braces ? -.-"

Comment: You don't need to parse it inside out. You need to recognize that your `variable` definition is fundamentally wrong for parsing something that is neither a variable nor as simply structured as a `Word`.

Comment: `function = Word(alphas) + Literal("(") + Optional(Word) + Literal(")")`
Currently not knowing a better name for variable.
`variable = Word(alphas) | OneOrMore(Word(alphas) + Literal("._:")) + Word(alphas) | function`

So something like this where I parse the whole function call again?
This should then parse words like `self.function` or `self.test.function(test)`